# I want to set a calculated priority using the server timestamp provided by Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to set the priority of a child using the server time stamp provided by Firebase, `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`:

```
mFirebaseref.child(userid).setPriority(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

But my case is inverse. I want to set negative `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` to move my child to the top based on time. Is it possible to do that in Firebase without using the local time stamp `System.CurrentTimeInMillis()`?

I would like to do something like this:

```
mFirebaseref.child(userid).setPriority(-ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the client side, `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is an object structured like this: `{.sv: "timestamp"}`

So, as you know, you can't easily do what you wanted. However, there may be a different solution. If, for example, you wanted the five most recent entries, you could still set the priority by `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`:

```
mFirebaseref.child(userid).setPriority(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

And then use the [`limitToLast()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries) method:

```
Query queryRef = mFirebaseref.limitToLast(5);
```

To get the five most recent entries.

Also, this may help: [Display posts in descending posted order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611356/display-posts-in-descending-posted-order)

Answer (score 3):

You are basically asking how to get negative server timestamp and it should work offline. I found a way, there is a hidden field you can use. A snippet from documentation:

```
Firebase offsetRef = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/.info/serverTimeOffset");
offsetRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    double offset = snapshot.getValue(Double.class);
    double estimatedServerTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis() + offset;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
    System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
  }
});
```

Comment: Link to (legacy) documentation in case anyone finds it helpful: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-latency