# firebaseArray descending order?

Tags: firebase, sorting

Using firebaseArray, is it possible to order by a specified child key:
(https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries)?

```
var fireRef = new Firebase(https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs);
var query = fireRef.orderByChild("echo").limitToFirst(25);
var todos = $firebaseArray(query);
```

However, by default, Firebase retrieves the keys in ascending order.

> Children with a numeric value come next, sorted in ascending order.

Is there any way to get results in the descending order *directly* from firebaseArray? For example, do they have anything like `.reverse()` or `.orderBy(desc, ...)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display posts in descending posted order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611356/display-posts-in-descending-posted-order)

Comment: I saw that, but that's a complicated solution. Do they have anything .reverse() or .orderBy(desc, ...)?

Comment: *Disclaimer: I work for Firebase* 
Nope. We're aware that such an addition would be useful, but it doesn't currently exist. In some cases you can invert your values to get the same result (i.e. `-1 * timestamp`). But that depends on the type of value you're storing.

Comment: Is there an example of the -1 * timestamp? This would be a very useful feature for Firebase

Comment: How i can multiply -1 * server value? [FirebaseServerValue.timestamp()]

Comment: @AndreyGagan I just inserted '1*timestap' when I insert other data.

Comment: @sung-kim What? So you write two times? It will perform mutable state. You cannot do this, it's bad.

Comment: @AndreyGagan I am not sure I understand this. Adding one more field won't hurt too much in my case. I meant -1*timestamp.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen will queryOrderedByChild("negative_timestamp") be slow when you have 100K of items? give that they are reversely stored and need to be reversely sorted each time?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer the original question, but for anyone using FirebaseUI Java/Android, with a `RecyclerView`, it's possible to order the `RecyclerView` in reverse, rather than using a query on Firebase:

Example:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
```

(Ensuring you set both before adding the layout manager to the `RecyclerView` also)

Github issue: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/90#issuecomment-230643303

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thanks a lot pal, that's just what I need

Comment: Much appreciated Alan, exactly what I was looking for. Is this more efficient code compared to trying to actually re-order the firebase database?

Comment: I haven't seen any documentation suggesting reversing the layout manager affects performance on android. Performance didn't diminish in my case anyway. It saved me the headache of dealing with more firebase queries and timestamps also 

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can order by date. Just use queryOrderedByChild(dateKey)
and it will be in asc order, to make desc you can do array.reverse()

```
POST_REF.queryOrderedByChild(PostKeys.kPostDate).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
  snapshot in

  var localPosts = [Post]()
    for item in snapshot.children {
      let postItem = Post(snapshot: item as! FDataSnapshot)
      localPosts.append(postItem)
    }
  //Display at desc order
   let reverseResults = localPosts.reverse() as [Post]
       completion(postsArray: reverseResults)
    }, withCancelBlock: { error in
   completion(postsArray: nil)
})
```