# Performing Mathematical Operations on kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

In one of the comments on this post: [firebaseArray descending order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31282204/firebasearray-descending-order), a Firebase employee suggests multiplying the timestamp by -1 in order to sort in descending order by date.

This is an idea that I'm trying to implement, however, I'm having a hard time doing it because `kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp` is a `NSDictionary` with the key ".sv" and a value of "timeStamp".

When I try to isolate the value, all I can get is an `NSString` that says "timeStamp".

Is there a way to perform mathematical operations on `kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp is a property that is really used as a placeholder that firebase fills in when writing data.

From the docs:

> Server Values - Placeholder values you may write into a Firebase
>   database as a value or priority that will automatically be populated
>   before writing to the Firebase database.
>
> kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp - The number of milliseconds since the
>   Unix epoch

So for example, if you wanted to base your timestamps on the Firebase server time, then

```
Firebase *timeStampsRef = [self.myRootRef childByAutoId];

[timeStampsRef setValue:kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp];

Firebase *timeStampsRef2 = [self.myRootRef childByAutoId];

[timeStampsRef2 setValue:kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp];
```

Would result in the following

```
-K861VyNBisoAL14dHsk: 1452890788194
-K861VyNBisoAL14dHsl: 1452890788195
```

If you want to sort Firebase data you should include a timestamp property as a child of the nodes you want to sort.

```
pizza_time
  node_id_0
   timeStamp: 20160109153000
   location: "Pizza House"
  node_id_1
   timeStamp: 20160110153000
   location: "Pizza Place"
  node_id_2
   timeStamp: 20160114153000
   location: "Pizza Busters"
```

You can then sort by date, query nodes from one date to another or a variety of other data acrobatics.