# limitTo(angularjs) or limitToFirst(firebase) don't work as expected

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to display the latest ads, I have some ads saved into Firebase and want to display the lasts added, they are stored with a timestamp property.

If I create the ng-repeat without **limitTo**, it works as expected, but when I use **limitTo** or even **limitToFirst**, it doesn't work as expected, it displays correctly the number of items I was going to display at the beginning but it skips some of them, and when I click the loadmore button, it loads more ads and display the ones that supposed to be there from the beginning.

Note that it should display two ads with dates **27th** **oct** but it only displays one.

Here a plunkr with a demo:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Ae8rlbD8Uob5TrAHrivz?p=preview

```
app.controller('publicCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
  $scope.loadmore = 6;
  $scope.latest = "-Addate";
  var listads = new Firebase("https://milocal.firebaseio.com/Users/Ovalle");
  $scope.listads = $firebaseArray(listads);

  $scope.loadmoreads = function(){
    //console.log("Cargando anuncios");
    $scope.loadmore += 2;
    $scope.listads = $firebaseArray(listads);
    console.log($scope.loadmore);
  }

});
```

in the HTML:

```
ng-repeat="ads in filteredAds = (listads | limitTo: loadmore | orderBy: latest)"
```

Hope someone can explain me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: You're definitely not filtering anything in your query from Firebase. `$firebaseArray(Firebase("https://milocal.firebaseio.com/Users/Ovalle"))` will load all children from that location. Can you point to the documentation where those `limitTo` and `orderBy` are defined? That way I can hopefully understand how this is supposed to work.

Comment: You start by limiting the array, effectively taking the first 6 elements of the not-ordered array, and then you order those 6 elements. You want the reverse: sort the array to have the most recent first, and only display the 6 first ones: `listads | orderBy: latest | limitTo: loadmore`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for helping. limitTo and orderBy are from the angularjs side I think, I used them to try to filter the data retrieved from that query. But from firebase side I also try var listads = new Firebase("https://milocal.firebaseio.com/Users/Ovalle"); $scope.listads = $firebaseArray(listads.orderByChild("-Addate").limitToFirst(6)); but it also does not work or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @JBNizet That works perfect, now that I see I just had to change the order of those directives. I understood really well what you said, if I dont find a firebase side method to do the same Im gonna do it that way. Thanksso much

Answer (score 0):

I changed your Plunkr to this:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ["firebase"]);

app.controller('publicCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
  $scope.loadmore = 1;
  $scope.latest = "-Addate";
  var listads = new Firebase("https://milocal.firebaseio.com/Users/Ovalle");
  var query = listads.orderByChild("-Addate").limitToFirst($scope.loadmore);
  $scope.listads = $firebaseArray(query);

  $scope.loadmoreads = function(){
    $scope.loadmore += 2;
    var query = listads.orderByChild("-Addate").limitToFirst($scope.loadmore);
    $scope.listads = $firebaseArray(query);
  }

});
```

It initially loads 2 items. Then when you click the "Load more" button, it loads 4. Then 6, etc.

Updated/forked plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/MUMerL?p=preview

Comment: The only problem is that is not ordering correctly, because I want to show the last ads added that's why I have **orderByChild("-Addate")**  instead of just **Added** for inverse order

Comment: Searching and searching I found this post where explains exactly what I need [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31282204/firebasearray-descending-order) and I was trying to store a negative timestamp but couldnt do it. If I manually store it in Firebase then I can see the order as I want, but the thing is that I dont know how to store them by code, any sample?