# firebase angular orderby timestamp not working

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

Am ordering the return item by timestamp , but it doesnt work 
it return items in order of date posted ,so new post go to bottom instead of on top

[image: push in reverse order]

this is my factory

```
.factory("items", function($firebaseArray) {
 var itemsRef = new Firebase("https//*****.firebaseio.com/comments");
  return itemsRef;
  })
```

this is my controller

```
.controller('streamCtrl', function($scope, items, $firebaseArray,$rootScope, $ionicModal, 
  ionicToast, $localStorage) {
  $scope.comments = $firebaseArray(items.orderByChild("timestamp"));
```

this is post with the time stamp which post successfull

```
$scope.comment.timestamp = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: shouldn't you be looking at time in descending order if you want most current on top?

Comment: am looking at from the descending point  , but am using firebase so ,how do i do this

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611356/display-posts-in-descending-posted-order