# Android - FirebaseListAdapter in reverse order?

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have a `FirebaseListAdapter` that populates a `ListView` with the last 5 items:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    FirebaseListAdapter<HashMap> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<HashMap>(getParentFragment().getActivity(),HashMap.class,R.layout.list_item,firebase.limitToLast(5)) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, HashMap hashMap, int i) {
            String title = hashMap.get("title").toString();
            String body = hashMap.get("body").toString();

            TextView title_txt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView body_txt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.body);

            title_txt.setText(title);
            body_txt.setText(body);
        }
    };

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The problem I have is that when a new item is pushed to Firebase, it is added to the bottom of the list. I want the newest items at the top of the list.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why would you bother to use Firebase adapter in the first place? I just had a look at Firebase Adapter and its just a simple adapter that extends from BaseAdapter. I highly recommend you to create your own adapter if you need to customize things.

Comment: Well, I am very new to Firebase and also not overly experienced in Java for android development. I saw that the FirebaseListAdapter was quick and easy to implement, so initially I decided it would be a good idea to use that.

Comment: @abeikverdi the adapters in FirebaseUI hide quite some complexity behind fairly little code. Based on what experience do you recommend writing your own?

Comment: @AlexBoullé here's a question about reversing the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33830387/how-reverse-the-data-fetched-with-firebaseui-android. For `FirebaseListAdapter` see https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/90

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen do I need to add more than setStackFromBottom(true) because all this does is makes the listview start from the bottom, not the top. What I need is it to add new items to the top of the listview, and be able to scroll down to older items like you would in a regular listview. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @ReazMurshed No, I am currently using a ListView

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen OP needs a simple reversed list. Android provides recycleview and it does pretty much all the complex caching and loading stuff efficiently. Why would would you want to use Firebase adapter that extends old BaseAdapter? That really ties your hands.

Comment: OP needs an inverted list that comes from the Firebase Database, which synchronizes data changes in realtime. This leads to numerous fun edge cases, which FirebaseUI handles. Have a look at the code of the [FirebaseListAdapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseListAdapter.java) and its underlying [FirebaseArray](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseArray.java). Then try to write one from scratch: it may be small, but it's not simple :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is not the exact solution of your problem of getting the data from firebase in a reverse order, but anyway, we've other work arounds.

The first work around is mentioned in a comment of using a custom adapter for your list.

To achieve the behaviour you need to get the firebase data in a list and then you've to reverse it yourself before passing it to an adapter. Simple!

The second work around is easy as pie and I think if you're using `RecyclerView` it could do the trick for you and I see it as the simplest way you can do the job.

Here's I'm modifying some of my code with `RecyclerView`

```
// Declare the RecyclerView and the LinearLayoutManager first
private RecyclerView listView;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
```

...

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    // Use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter here

    // Here you modify your LinearLayoutManager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

    // Now set the layout manager and the adapter to the RecyclerView
    listView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

By setting `mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);` - you're reversing your layout and `mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);` positions the view to the top of your list.

Migrating to `RecyclerView` is simple. Your layout will be something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

You need to have `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` can be found here in [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) library.

**Note:** Do not use `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` as the `setReverseLayout` and `setStackFromEnd` functions won't be found in `RecyclerView.LayoutManager`. Use `LinearLayoutManager` as stated.

**Update**

Here's how you can handle the click events of your items in the list.

You had to declare a `ViewHolder` to implement the `RecyclerView` right? Just add another function inside your `ViewHolder` class like the example below and call this function after the `setText` functions you've got there.

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setClickEvent() {
        // Set the onClickListener on mView
        // mView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener)...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having some issues with the RecyclerView. I'm guessing where you have used my original code, the listView is the RecyclerView? When I do setAdapter(adapter) on the recyclerView, it does not work: set adapter (android.support.v7.widget.recyclerview.adapter) cannot be applied to (com.firebase.ui..FirebaseListAdapter<java.util.Hashmap>)

Comment: Yes your `listView` is `RecyclerView`, you guessed it right. And sorry I put another little mistake. Please see this answer from @FrankVanPuffelen  http://stackoverflow.com/a/31122788/3145960 to see how to use `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` to work with `RecyclerView`. I'm editing the answer.

Comment: This seems to be working, as in, it adds the newest to the top. I am still a bit stuck on how to detect click events on the items in the RecyclerVIew. Would you be able to explain briefly how to detect click events? Basically, I need to open a new fragment when one of the items is clicked. I had it working with ListView. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're already extending `FirebaseListAdapter` to implement `populateView`, you can go ahead and override `getItem` as well to invert the item lookup:

```
@Override
public HashMap getItem(int pos) {
    return super.getItem(getCount() - 1 - pos);
}
```

If you're not using `RecyclerView` this is a simple way to reverse the *data* without extending any more classes than necessary. Obviously this will reverse any `AdapterView` subclass backed by this adapter, if you choose to reuse it.

Comment: Best one! This is the simples way to do the Job, combined with orderByChild(). Thanks.