# Firebase - OrderByChild based on timestamp

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following data structure which I **want to sort by uploaded_on, where the newest timestamp comes first**:

```
"hd2CnPPZ5FMKjpzFJNUc4xVLVUW2" : {
  "media" : {
    "-KJkxpnRg_2ZK4tEjGBN" : {
      "uploaded_on" : 1465405365513,
      "url" : "<my-firebase-storage-url>"
    },
```

And I have the following code to retrieve the data and sort it:

```
FIREBASE_REF.database().ref(`${this.props.auth.user.uid}/media`).orderByChild('uploaded_on').on('value', (snapshot) => {
  this.props.dispatch(mediaActions.updateMedia(snapshot.val()));
});
```

However, my items do not get ordered properly and the the oldest timestamp comes first. I tried by putting a minus infront of the uploaded_on, but that does not make any difference.

Any pointers in what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are the items ordered in just the reverse order you want them?

Comment: Yes. Currently ordered from June 8th to June 10th for example. I want the latest (June 10th) as first item.

Comment: Found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25613337/4741567