# how to retrieve data from firebase in reverse order

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to know how to retrieve data from firebase in reverse order

Second question is 
how to notify after addchild method ??

i want to notify adapter after add child 
so i tried to make this 
but

> reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent

but it executed only one time after

> addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() finished ???

.........................................................................

Thank You :)

How to make this ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611356/display-posts-in-descending-posted-order

Comment: Ok Thanks Frank 
but what about second question  ?

Comment: Please limit your posts to a single question if they are unrelated