# Can I change the order of children in firebase

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

firebase stores data according to the order of saving. Is it possible to tell firebase to store the child on top of / after this particular child? For example if I want to save the new data right before 'Fish' instead of after 'Fish' , is it possible to do so. Thanks in advance

```
Pets :

 Name : Cat
 ID   : 123

 Name : Dog
 ID   : 456

 Name :Fish
 ID   :789
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a specific ordering for children in mind for your app, then you should introduce a child value that sorts the way you want them to appear.  You don't really have another way to "force" the ordering.  It's up to you to write child values that sort the way you expect, and it's up to your client code to query them for that order.

Comment: Can I atleast have them in ascending or descending order ? If I put a value that says the way in which they should appear

Comment: You can put two different values that sort either way. You can't do it both with one item. Realtime Database only sorts ascending.

Comment: Query results are returned in ascending order of their value. If you want them reverse, you can either do that client-side after retrieving the values, or by storing an inverted value in a property. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611356/display-posts-in-descending-posted-order

Answer (score 0):

You have no control over the order in which Firebase stores nodes.

The console displays nodes in lexicographical order of their keys, so if you use `push` that means they are shown in the order you added them. There is no way to change, or reverse this.

Comment: Thank  you for the valuble input